# UNION table name error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I would like to know how to use one side of a union and not the other. So look at the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 0 and 1=2 
UNION 
SELECT table_name,2,3 from information_schema.tables where table_schema='sqlhack'
```

Now when I enter this into phpMyAdmin to test the query I get an error saying no table named users in the information schema, however when I have just this:

```
 SELECT table_name,2,3 from information_schema.tables where table_schema='sqlhack'
```

I get the desired result, which is all the tables which belong to sqlhack.
So I would like to know how can I make it that it only does the 2nd select query? Or just not get the error for the first SELECT query.

I am following [this](http://sechow.com/bricks/docs/content-page-1.html) site, but with my own database if that helps clarify.

Comment: Just run the second query.  Why are you including the first if you don't want to use it?

Comment: Do you have users table? If have, use information_schema.users

Comment: @GordonLinoff its for the purpose of an sql injection and the first part is needed for normal use. I am using phpMyAdmin first so its not my coding which is the issue but its the straight statement

Comment: @Loc I don't which is why I get the error, but this is not the point I am trying to search in tables and find all tables related to the sqlhack database.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `SELECT` is trying to select from table `users`. The second verifies that the table `sqlhack` exists; it doesn't verify that `users` exists.

Comment: How can I make it verify both, if that is possible?

Comment: Just run `SELECT table_name,2,3 from information_schema.tables where table_schema IN('sqlhack', 'users')`

Comment: Well, does the table actually exist?

Comment: No but its not supposed to, I am not trying to search in `information_schema.users` because this should not exist in my schema

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't make sense. You are running `SELECT * FROM users ...`. Does that `users` table exist, or not? If not, you can't do a `SELECT` on it.

Comment: No it does exist just not in the information_schema, which why I assume I am getting the error

Answer (score 1):

I usually stay away from the information_schema.tables since they seldom have all the details I want.

To test existence of a table using T-SQL specific command.

```
-- Does the schema.table exist?  NULL if not, otherwise a number
select OBJECT_ID('sqlhack.users', 'Table') as my_id
```